# How to change text of password message on pdf file

Tags: c#, selectpdf

I am using c# `SelectPdf` library to create a password protected pdf file.
Is it possible to change the text the user sees when he is trying to open the file?

The default text is something like: "this file is password protected. please provide a password."

Comment: Please provide the code what you tried. Your question should be [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by _"the text the user see's when he is trying to open the file"_?

Answer (score 2):

The dialog that is displayed when you open a password protected file is going to be controlled by the application displaying it, and not the file itself. The application will simply check to see if it is password protected and present it's dialog to open, therefore the text displayed is controlled by the application and you will be unable to change it.

Comment: The default text is something like: "this file is password protected. please provide a password." can I change it by code?

Comment: As above, I would say not possible. Unless there was a specific property in the PDF specification to manage that, you cannot change what the parent application will say.